# Execute minimal css rule sets with both common and specific parts using scss?

Tags: css, sass

```
    .name {
        %common {
            // common stuff
        }  

        &__first-type {
            @extend %common;
            // first type thing
        }
        enter code here
        &__second-type {
            @extend %common;
            // second type thing
        }
    }
```

I want to collapse all thing in name class 
(first-type, second-type, and also a common part)
but I don't want anything more in the executed CSS file.

```
    .name__first-type, .name__second-type {
        //common thing
    }

    .name__first-type {
        //first type thing
    }

    .name__second-type {
        //second type thing
    }
```

can I do this thing without separating non-executable common(%common)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate those two class like this.

```
    %name__common {
        // common stuff
    }  
    .name {
        &__first-type {
            @extend %name__common;
            // first type thing
        }

        &__second-type {
            @extend %name__common;
            // second type thing
        }
```

If you mater nice project architecture you can either put this %name__common{...} in partial file such as _commons.scss
or try to change your project coding style.